# C++ ODBC problem with sqlucode.h header

Tags: visual-c++, odbc, linker

I found a great C++/ODBC example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/easyodbc.aspx)...

The project I downloaded builds great and everything works.  However, when I copy the .cpp and .h files into another project, I seem to have a linking problem.

The `SQLConnect` function in sql.h is the one I want.  When I right-click this function in the `easyodbc.h` file in the project I downloaded, it jumps to the declaration in sql.h.  Life is good.

However, in the project I created, when I do this it jumps to a UNICODE definition in sqlucode.h.  This seems to be causing problems and my test project crashes.

I don't have an `#include` for sqlucdode.h anywhere in my project, yet it still resolves the declaration to the one in sqlucode.h.  How can I prevent this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you have a preprocessor problem rather than a linking problem.

You probably have a preprocessor definition for `UNICODE` (or `_UNICODE`) in your project file. In Visual C++ 2005 and 2008 you can fix this by going to your project properties and changing Character Set from **Use Unicode Character Set** to **Use Multi-Byte Character Set**. When you apply this setting, Visual Studio fixes up the right preprocessor and linker settings for you.

If you have an earlier version of Visual Studio you can still fix it by changing the preprocessor definitions for `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` to `_MBCS` - it's just you'll have to find them yourself.

EDIT: I just downloaded that example code and tried it - good news, it's exactly as I guessed, change to a multibyte character set and you'll be fine.

Comment: where/how exactly would I add this define?  I've tried a few things but I'm still getting build errors: error C2664: 'SQLConnectW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'SQLCHAR *' to 'SQLWCHAR *'

Comment: It depends what version of Visual C++ you're using - can you specify?

Comment: That did it!  I also had to open the project by itself- I had a solution with other C# projects in it, for some reason that made it resolve to sqlucode.h even with the project set to MBCS.  Thanks!!!